# FFmpeg pauses the extraction of frames at 20% (but when closed, dumps all frames to disk)

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract frames from a video using FFmpeg. I want to be able to control which frames to extract, by setting the start, end and FPS values.

The problem is, that after the extraction begins, FFmpeg stops after ~20% of the way. It always stops there, independently of the frame count.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
var start = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SelectionSlider.LowerValue);
var end = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SelectionSlider.UpperValue);
var fps = FpsIntegerUpDown.Value;
var count = CountFrames(); //Duration x FPS
var folder = Path.Combine(RootFolder, "Import");
var path = Path.Combine(folder, $"%0{count.ToString().Length + 1}d.png");

try
{
    //Create temporary folder.
    if (Directory.Exists(folder))
        Directory.Delete(folder, true);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

    CaptureProgressBar.Value = 0;
    CaptureProgressBar.Maximum = count;

    var info = new ProcessStartInfo(UserSettings.All.FfmpegLocation)
    {
        Arguments = $" -i \"{VideoPath}\" -vsync 2 -progress pipe:1 -vf scale={VideoWidth}:{VideoHeight} -ss {start:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff} -to {end:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff} -hide_banner -c:v png -r {fps} -vframes {count} \"{path}\"",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
     };

     _process = new Process();
     _process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
     {
         Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
             return;

         var parsed = e.Data.Split('=');

         switch (parsed[0])
         {
             case "frame":
                 Dispatcher?.InvokeAsync(() => { CaptureProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToDouble(parsed[1]); });
                 break;

             case "progress":
                 if (parsed[1] == "end" && IsLoaded)
                     GetFiles(folder); //Get all files from the output folder.

                 break;
          }
    };

_process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        throw new Exception("Error while capturing frames with FFmpeg.") { HelpLink = $"Command:\n\r{info.Arguments}\n\rResult:\n\r{e.Data}" };
};

_process.StartInfo = info;
_process.Start();
_process.BeginOutputReadLine();

//Just to wait...
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _process.WaitForExit());
```

So, after starting the import process, FFmpeg will extract some frames, and after reaching around 20%, it will pause the extraction.

```
frame=95
fps=5.79
stream_0_0_q=-0.0
bitrate=N/A
total_size=N/A
out_time_us=1400000
out_time_ms=1400000
out_time=00:00:01.400000
dup_frames=0
drop_frames=0
speed=0.0854x

progress=continue
frame=106
fps=6.25
stream_0_0_q=-0.0
bitrate=N/A
total_size=N/A
out_time_us=1583333
out_time_ms=1583333
out_time=00:00:01.583333
dup_frames=0
drop_frames=0
speed=0.0933x
progress=continue

frame=117
fps=6.67
stream_0_0_q=-0.0
bitrate=N/A
total_size=N/A
out_time_us=1766667
out_time_ms=1766667
out_time=00:00:01.766667
dup_frames=0
drop_frames=0
speed=0.101x
progress=continue
```

Something strange: if I close the app while is the extraction is paused, suddenly FFmpeg will dump all frames to the folder.

Why would FFmpeg pause the extraction at all (But continue doing in memory)? 
Is there any way for me to force FFmpeg to extract the frames normally?

PS: It does not happen while using FFmpeg via cmd, so it must be something in code.

Comment: Is this a programming question? or the question about how 3rd party program (ffmpeg) works?

Comment: Does FFmpeg have the same issue when run directly? If so, this is not a "C# question" ..

Comment: It is a programming question. I understand now what's happening, I'm setting to redirect the `stderr` but I was not listening via `BeginErrorReadLine()`.

By removing the `RedirectStandardError  = true` or adding `BeginErrorReadLine()` the import will work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must not set `RedirectStandardError = true` without actually processing its data via `BeginErrorReadLine()`.

So I just need to set `RedirectStandardError = false` or I should just add `BeginErrorReadLine()`.